# Magento CE 1.7.0.2 - Unable to log in to admin panel with Chrome

Tags: magento, google-chrome, magento-1.7

I'm having an unusual issue and it doesn't seem to be related to other posts I've found. I'm logging into my Magento install that I have setup through MAMP on my local. It doesn't say "invalid password" or anything of that nature, it just refreshes itself. I've tried modifying .htaccess and posting it to Magento forum but nothing. I hit "submit" and it just seems to refresh the page. Is this a redirect issue? It works perfectly fine on Firefox but for some reason Chrome just won't allow access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how Chrome handles cookies and it can happen on production sites as well as local installs.

Fastest fix is to log into the DB (with PHPMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, whatever), go to the table core_config_data and find the column labeled "path" with an entry that matches "web/cookie/cookie_httponly" - it should be closer to the end. You'll need to set the value column to NULL. Clear cache from the /var folder and you should be good.

Some sites will tell you to modify Varien.php - I've tried this and you can end up with a log file that can grow up to 2GB or more because you commented out fields that Magento references every time you pull data from a cookie. Not good. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Glad it worked. I use to modify the following but it seems to not be necessary anymore. I'll post it in case others need it. NOTE: You may get a message stating your server is configured incorrectly. I've never had an issue with security on production environments but again, I normally only nullify the "httponly" entry.


    Update core_config_data > web/cookie/cookie_path to NULL
    Update core_config_data > web/cookie/cookie_domain to NULL
    Update core_config_data > web/cookie/cookie_httponly to NULL

Answer (score 0):

I did the above solution and it worked for me as well, I just wanted to add that typing in "NULL" in the value field is different from selecting the check box on PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file first then make comment out on this section (it's lines 85 to 102). 
\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

```
/*
// session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```